# Postal Code error PayPal (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card, paypal-sandbox, postal-code

I want to integrate PayPal on my website with PayPal integration wizard. I use PayPal API and expresscheckout.php, paypalfunctions.php generated by PayPal Integration Wizard.

I wrote form to fill billing data to post to PayPal, but it returns Error Code: 10712, which mean is "There's an error with this transaction. Please enter a valid postal code in the billing address." and recommended solution is " Please enter your five digit postal code in the billing address. " 
Okay, that's right, but I tried to use 95131 which is valid ZIP from California, and it's five digits.

What could be the problem? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

From the tags on your question I'm assuming you're using the PayPal Sandbox. If so, make sure you are using a valid "test" credit card number, such as the ones [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm), or try following the following process, copied from [this PayPal Developer Network thread](https://www.x.com/thread/8004):

> Please follow the steps below to generate a credit card number for testing 
>   PayPal Account Optional within the Sandbox.
>
> Log in to your Sandbox Account
>   Click 'Profile'
>   Click on 'Credit Cards' under Financial Information
>   Click the ''Add' button, as if you are adding a credit card to the account
>
> Use the credit card number that is automatically generated here as the 
>   credit card of your buyer
>
> Note: Do not click on the 'Add Card' button as this will add the credit card 
>   to your Sandbox account. If it is added to your Sandbox account, it cannot 
>   be used to make a non-PayPal account payment.

Comment: yes, u are right, sandbox, and i think it's valid test credit card because paypal to paypal payment is working. i get error when i try to use test credit card to pay. (country, city, state, zip, etc generated by paypal (and real valid datas))

Comment: i receive billing informations from customer (card type valid, card number valid, street, city, state is okay, country/currency code is okay, everything fine but postal code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering the billing zip code for PayPal, or the billing zip code of the client?  Usually, most credit card transactions want the latter - they couldn't care less about the zip code of the processor or the billing party.

Comment: Then I am afraid I am uncertain - sorry.

Comment: i'm too :\ i don't know what's problem with 95131, why isn't it five digit by paypal? (or php made mistake?)

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying your information (on a page, command line, etc.) exactly as it's being sent to the servers. Perhaps there's a carriage return or something like that. Either way, PayPal has a number of testing environments for you to use once you have some testing variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible there's nothing wrong with your posted data at all.  When I was having problems with PayPal's test site I spoke to support and was advised to skip the test environment and just post a live transaction with a $1.00 charge.  It worked.  Then I did nothing but switch from the live site (https://payflowpro.paypal.com/ for the token and https://payflowlink.paypal.com/ for the data post) to the test site (https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/ for the token and https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/ for the post), posted *exactly the same data*, and it failed with this error.  I tried it with the generated sandbox Visa number and the error remained.  I tried both zip and ZIP+4.  My Rails app spits out all the data its sending, so I know for sure what's going out.  PayPal appears to have a long history of its test environment just not working.